# Hibernate query inner join on unmapped table (unidirectional)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I do have a problem query problem with spring and hibernate.

I've got a class called Car which maps ManyToMany to my class Inventory. Inventory btw holds no references to the Car class. 
This causes spring and hibernate to create the mapping table car_loading with a fk to the car and a fk to the inventory table.

I now want to query the inventory for a special car:

```
String squery = "SELECT i from Inventory i, car_loading loads WHERE i.id = loads.loading AND car = ?";
```

But I am getting the exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: car_loading is not mapped
```

FYI: Hibernate doesn't support the JOIN ON x.a = y.b leading me to do it that way...

Thanks inn advance for any help!

### EDIT - My Mapping

```
public class Car {

    @OneToOne
    private Driver driver;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Inventory> loading = new ArrayList<Inventory>();   

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd:MM:yyy HH:mm")
    private Date lastModified;
    //...
}

public class Inventory {

    private Integer shouldAmount;

    private Integer minAmount;

    private Integer isAmount;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd:MM:yyy HH:mm")
    private Date lastModified;
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this question and wanted to updated it. I did it the wrong way around. I could simply query the car and return all inventorys within this car. Because there is a relation from car to inventory, but not the other way around. So query a specific car and simply return the inventory list attribute did it for me...

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the mapping table explicitly, hibernate adds it automatically when you use entity's properties.
For your situation the query should look like:

```
"select c.loading from Car c where c = ?"
```

or just get a car object `Car car = session.get(Car.class, id)`, then use getter as ususal `Collection<Inventory> loading = car.getLoading();`

Comment: I can't use c.loading, because loading is not a field in Car causing an unknown field loading exception. That's my problem, the reference is unidirectional

Comment: Show your classes and mapping, please.

Comment: Hmm it seems that I still have problems with this. Tried it with a native query using joins, but i the production server has problems with that, I've posted my mapping ...

Comment: `Car.loading` is a many-to-many field. Why is it unknown? Do you use HQL? This is very basic use-case of hibernate. Maybe you are doing something wrong in infrastructure code. Try to compose a minimal test case.